# ReactJs - How to have multiple entrypoints in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am trying to separate my app in two parts : public and admin. I want admin to be protected by a htpasswd file. It works well when my admin part is just pure html. But I want to also use React.
So I want React to have 2 entrypoints (like 2 react app but in one). I followed those posts :

- [How to serve multiple HTML files with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304189/how-to-serve-multiple-html-files-with-react)
- [multiple entry points by using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53480066/multiple-entry-points-by-using-create-react-app)

But it doesn't work : when I use `npm run start`, the console is stuck at `Starting the development server...` forever. (Nothing is shown in verbose mode).

Here a sample of my `webpack.config.js` (return value of `module.exports = function (webpackEnv)`)

```
return {
        target: ["browserslist"],
        // Webpack noise constrained to errors and warnings
        stats: "errors-warnings",
        mode: isEnvProduction ? "production" : isEnvDevelopment && "development",
        // Stop compilation early in production
        bail: isEnvProduction,
        devtool: isEnvProduction
            ? shouldUseSourceMap
                ? "source-map"
                : false
            : isEnvDevelopment && "cheap-module-source-map",
        // These are the "entry points" to our application.
        // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
        entry: {
            index: paths.appIndexJs,
            admin: paths.appPath + "/admin/index.js"
        },
        output: {
            // The build folder.
            path: paths.appBuild,
            // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
            pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
            // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
            // In development, it does not produce real files.
            filename: isEnvProduction
                ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js"
                : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/bundle.js",
            // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
            chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
                ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js"
                : isEnvDevelopment && "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
            assetModuleFilename: "static/media/[name].[hash][ext]",
            // webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
            // It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
            // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
            publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
            // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
            devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
                ? info =>
                    path
                        .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
                        .replace(/\\/g, "/")
                : isEnvDevelopment &&
                (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")),
        },
        cache: {
            type: "filesystem",
            version: createEnvironmentHash(env.raw),
            cacheDirectory: paths.appWebpackCache,
            store: "pack",
            buildDependencies: {
                defaultWebpack: ["webpack/lib/"],
                config: [__filename],
                tsconfig: [paths.appTsConfig, paths.appJsConfig].filter(f =>
                    fs.existsSync(f)
                ),
            },
        },
        infrastructureLogging: {
            level: "none",
        },
        optimization: {
            minimize: isEnvProduction,
            minimizer: [
                // This is only used in production mode
                new TerserPlugin({
                    terserOptions: {
                        parse: {
                            // We want terser to parse ecma 8 code. However, we don't want it
                            // to apply any minification steps that turns valid ecma 5 code
                            // into invalid ecma 5 code. This is why the 'compress' and 'output'
                            // sections only apply transformations that are ecma 5 safe
                            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4234
                            ecma: 8,
                        },
                        compress: {
                            ecma: 5,
                            warnings: false,
                            // Disabled because of an issue with Uglify breaking seemingly valid code:
                            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2376
                            // Pending further investigation:
                            // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/2011
                            comparisons: false,
                            // Disabled because of an issue with Terser breaking valid code:
                            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5250
                            // Pending further investigation:
                            // https://github.com/terser-js/terser/issues/120
                            inline: 2,
                        },
                        mangle: {
                            safari10: true,
                        },
                        // Added for profiling in devtools
                        keep_classnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
                        keep_fnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
                        output: {
                            ecma: 5,
                            comments: false,
                            // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
                            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
                            ascii_only: true,
                        },
                    },
                }),
                // This is only used in production mode
                new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            // This allows you to set a fallback for where webpack should look for modules.
            // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
            // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
            modules: ["node_modules", paths.appNodeModules].concat(
                modules.additionalModulePaths || []
            ),
            // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
            // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
            // some tools, although we do not recommend using it, see:
            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/290
            // `web` extension prefixes have been added for better support
            // for React Native Web.
            extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
                .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
                .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes("ts")),
            alias: {
                // Support React Native Web
                // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
                "react-native": "react-native-web",
                // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
                ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
                    "react-dom$": "react-dom/profiling",
                    "scheduler/tracing": "scheduler/tracing-profiling",
                }),
                ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
            },
            plugins: [
                // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
                // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
                // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
                // please link the files into your node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
                // Make sure your source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
                new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [
                    paths.appPackageJson,
                    reactRefreshRuntimeEntry,
                    reactRefreshWebpackPluginRuntimeEntry,
                    babelRuntimeEntry,
                    babelRuntimeEntryHelpers,
                    babelRuntimeRegenerator,
                ]),
            ],
        },
        module: {
            strictExportPresence: true,
            rules: [
                // Handle node_modules packages that contain sourcemaps
                shouldUseSourceMap && {
                    enforce: "pre",
                    exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
                    test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx|css)$/,
                    loader: require.resolve("source-map-loader"),
                },
                {
                    // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
                    // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
                    // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
                    oneOf: [
                        // TODO: Merge this config once `image/avif` is in the mime-db
                        // https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db
                        {
                            test: [/\.avif$/],
                            type: "asset",
                            mimetype: "image/avif",
                            parser: {
                                dataUrlCondition: {
                                    maxSize: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
                        // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
                        // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
                        {
                            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
                            type: "asset",
                            parser: {
                                dataUrlCondition: {
                                    maxSize: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            test: /\.svg$/,
                            use: [
                                {
                                    loader: require.resolve("@svgr/webpack"),
                                    options: {
                                        prettier: false,
                                        svgo: false,
                                        svgoConfig: {
                                            plugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
                                        },
                                        titleProp: true,
                                        ref: true,
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    loader: require.resolve("file-loader"),
                                    options: {
                                        name: "static/media/[name].[hash].[ext]",
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                            issuer: {
                                and: [/\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx|md|mdx)$/],
                            },
                        },
                        // Process application JS with Babel.
                        // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
                        {
                            test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                            include: paths.appSrc,
                            loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
                            options: {
                                customize: require.resolve(
                                    "babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides"
                                ),
                                presets: [
                                    [
                                        require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app"),
                                        {
                                            runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? "automatic" : "classic",
                                        },
                                    ],
                                ],

                                plugins: [
                                    isEnvDevelopment &&
                                    shouldUseReactRefresh &&
                                    require.resolve("react-refresh/babel"),
                                ].filter(Boolean),
                                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                                cacheDirectory: true,
                                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                                cacheCompression: false,
                                compact: isEnvProduction,
                            },
                        },
                        // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
                        // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
                        {
                            test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
                            exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
                            loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
                            options: {
                                babelrc: false,
                                configFile: false,
                                compact: false,
                                presets: [
                                    [
                                        require.resolve("babel-preset-react-app/dependencies"),
                                        {helpers: true},
                                    ],
                                ],
                                cacheDirectory: true,
                                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                                cacheCompression: false,

                                // Babel sourcemaps are needed for debugging into node_modules
                                // code.  Without the options below, debuggers like VSCode
                                // show incorrect code and set breakpoints on the wrong lines.
                                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                            },
                        },
                        // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
                        // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
                        // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
                        // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
                        // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
                        // of CSS.
                        // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
                        {
                            test: cssRegex,
                            exclude: cssModuleRegex,
                            use: getStyleLoaders({
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                                modules: {
                                    mode: "icss",
                                },
                            }),
                            // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
                            // containing package claims to have no side effects.
                            // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
                            // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
                            sideEffects: true,
                        },
                        // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
                        // using the extension .module.css
                        {
                            test: cssModuleRegex,
                            use: getStyleLoaders({
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                                    ? shouldUseSourceMap
                                    : isEnvDevelopment,
                                modules: {
                                    mode: "local",
                                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                                },
                            }),
                        },
                        // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
                        // By default we support SASS Modules with the
                        // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
                        {
                            test: sassRegex,
                            exclude: sassModuleRegex,
                            use: getStyleLoaders(
                                {
                                    importLoaders: 3,
                                    sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                                        ? shouldUseSourceMap
                                        : isEnvDevelopment,
                                    modules: {
                                        mode: "icss",
                                    },
                                },
                                "sass-loader"
                            ),
                            // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
                            // containing package claims to have no side effects.
                            // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
                            // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
                            sideEffects: true,
                        },
                        // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
                        // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
                        {
                            test: sassModuleRegex,
                            use: getStyleLoaders(
                                {
                                    importLoaders: 3,
                                    sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                                        ? shouldUseSourceMap
                                        : isEnvDevelopment,
                                    modules: {
                                        mode: "local",
                                        getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                                    },
                                },
                                "sass-loader"
                            ),
                        },
                        // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
                        // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
                        // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
                        // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
                        // that fall through the other loaders.
                        {
                            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
                            // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
                            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
                            // by webpacks internal loaders.
                            exclude: [/^$/, /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
                            type: "asset/resource",
                        },
                        // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
                        // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
                    ],
                },
            ].filter(Boolean),
        },
        plugins: [
            // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
                Object.assign(
                    {},
                    {
                        inject: true,
                        chunks: ["index"],
                        template: paths.appHtml,
                        filename: "index.html"
                    },
                    isEnvProduction
                        ? {
                            minify: {
                                removeComments: true,
                                collapseWhitespace: true,
                                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                                useShortDoctype: true,
                                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                                keepClosingSlash: true,
                                minifyJS: true,
                                minifyCSS: true,
                                minifyURLs: true,
                            },
                        }
                        : undefined
                )
            ),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
                Object.assign(
                    {},
                    {
                        inject: true,
                        chunks: ["admin"],
                        template: paths.appAdminHtml,
                        filename: "admin.html",
                    },
                    isEnvProduction
                        ? {
                            minify: {
                                removeComments: true,
                                collapseWhitespace: true,
                                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                                useShortDoctype: true,
                                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                                keepClosingSlash: true,
                                minifyJS: true,
                                minifyCSS: true,
                                minifyURLs: true,
                            },
                        }
                        : undefined
                )
            ),
            // Inlines the webpack runtime script. This script is too small to warrant
            // a network request.
            // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5358
            isEnvProduction &&
            shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
            new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime-.+[.]js/]),
            // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
            // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
            // <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
            // It will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
            // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
            new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
            // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
            // the requesting resource.
            new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
            // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
            // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
            // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV is set to production
            // during a production build.
            // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
            new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
            // Experimental hot reloading for React .
            // https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-refresh
            isEnvDevelopment &&
            shouldUseReactRefresh &&
            new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin({
                overlay: false,
            }),
            // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
            // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
            // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/240
            isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
            isEnvProduction &&
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
                // both options are optional
                filename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css",
                chunkFilename: "static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css",
            }),
            // Generate an asset manifest file with the following content:
            // - "files" key: Mapping of all asset filenames to their corresponding
            //   output file so that tools can pick it up without having to parse
            //   `index.html`
            // - "entrypoints" key: Array of files which are included in `index.html`,
            //   can be used to reconstruct the HTML if necessary
            new WebpackManifestPlugin({
                fileName: "asset-manifest.json",
                publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
                generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
                    const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
                        manifest[file.name] = file.path;
                        return manifest;
                    }, seed);

                    let entrypointFiles = [];
                    for (let [entryFile, fileName] of Object.entries(entrypoints)) {
                        let notMapFiles = fileName.filter(fileName => !fileName.endsWith(".map"));
                        entrypointFiles = entrypointFiles.concat(notMapFiles);
                    }

                    return {
                        files: manifestFiles,
                        entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
                    };
                },
            }),
            // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
            // by default due to how webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
            // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
            // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
            // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
                resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
                contextRegExp: /moment$/,
            }),
            // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
            // the HTML & assets that are part of the webpack build.
            isEnvProduction &&
            fs.existsSync(swSrc) &&
            new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest({
                swSrc,
                dontCacheBustURLsMatching: /\.[0-9a-f]{8}\./,
                exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/, /LICENSE/],
                // Bump up the default maximum size (2mb) that's precached,
                // to make lazy-loading failure scenarios less likely.
                // See https://github.com/cra-template/pwa/issues/13#issuecomment-722667270
                maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
            }),
            // TypeScript type checking
            useTypeScript &&
            new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
                async: isEnvDevelopment,
                typescript: {
                    typescriptPath: resolve.sync("typescript", {
                        basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
                    }),
                    configOverwrite: {
                        compilerOptions: {
                            sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                                ? shouldUseSourceMap
                                : isEnvDevelopment,
                            skipLibCheck: true,
                            inlineSourceMap: false,
                            declarationMap: false,
                            noEmit: true,
                            incremental: true,
                            tsBuildInfoFile: paths.appTsBuildInfoFile,
                        },
                    },
                    context: paths.appPath,
                    diagnosticOptions: {
                        syntactic: true,
                    },
                    mode: "write-references",
                    // profile: true,
                },
                issue: {
                    // This one is specifically to match during CI tests,
                    // as micromatch doesn't match
                    // '../cra-template-typescript/template/src/App.tsx'
                    // otherwise.
                    include: [
                        {file: "../**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"},
                        {file: "**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"},
                    ],
                    exclude: [
                        {file: "**/src/**/__tests__/**"},
                        {file: "**/src/**/?(*.){spec|test}.*"},
                        {file: "**/src/setupProxy.*"},
                        {file: "**/src/setupTests.*"},
                    ],
                },
                logger: {
                    infrastructure: "silent",
                },
            }),
            !disableESLintPlugin &&
            new ESLintPlugin({
                // Plugin options
                extensions: ["js", "mjs", "jsx", "ts", "tsx"],
                formatter: require.resolve("react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter"),
                eslintPath: require.resolve("eslint"),
                failOnError: !(isEnvDevelopment && emitErrorsAsWarnings),
                context: paths.appSrc,
                cache: true,
                cacheLocation: path.resolve(
                    paths.appNodeModules,
                    ".cache/.eslintcache"
                ),
                // ESLint class options
                cwd: paths.appPath,
                resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
                baseConfig: {
                    extends: [require.resolve("eslint-config-react-app/base")],
                    rules: {
                        ...(!hasJsxRuntime && {
                            "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "error",
                        }),
                    },
                },
            }),
        ].filter(Boolean),
        // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
        // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
        performance: false,
    };
```

And my `paths.js`

```
"use strict";

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const getPublicUrlOrPath = require("react-dev-utils/getPublicUrlOrPath");

// Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
// https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/637
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

// We use `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable or "homepage" field to infer
// "public path" at which the app is served.
// webpack needs to know it to put the right <script> hrefs into HTML even in
// single-page apps that may serve index.html for nested URLs like /todos/42.
// We can't use a relative path in HTML because we don't want to load something
// like /todos/42/static/js/bundle.7289d.js. We have to know the root.
const publicUrlOrPath = getPublicUrlOrPath(
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
    require(resolveApp("package.json")).homepage,
    process.env.PUBLIC_URL
);

const buildPath = process.env.BUILD_PATH || "build";

const moduleFileExtensions = [
    "web.mjs",
    "mjs",
    "web.js",
    "js",
    "web.ts",
    "ts",
    "web.tsx",
    "tsx",
    "json",
    "web.jsx",
    "jsx",
];

// Resolve file paths in the same order as webpack
const resolveModule = (resolveFn, filePath) => {
    const extension = moduleFileExtensions.find(extension =>
        fs.existsSync(resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`))
    );

    if (extension) {
        return resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`);
    }

    return resolveFn(`${filePath}.js`);
};

// config after eject: we're in ./config/
module.exports = {
    dotenv: resolveApp(".env"),
    appPath: resolveApp("."),
    appBuild: resolveApp(buildPath),
    appPublic: resolveApp("public"),
    appHtml: resolveApp("public/index.html"),
    appAdminHtml: resolveApp("admin/admin.html"),
    appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, "src/index"),
    appPackageJson: resolveApp("package.json"),
    appSrc: resolveApp("src"),
    appTsConfig: resolveApp("tsconfig.json"),
    appJsConfig: resolveApp("jsconfig.json"),
    yarnLockFile: resolveApp("yarn.lock"),
    testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, "src/setupTests"),
    proxySetup: resolveApp("src/setupProxy.js"),
    appNodeModules: resolveApp("node_modules"),
    appWebpackCache: resolveApp("node_modules/.cache"),
    appTsBuildInfoFile: resolveApp("node_modules/.cache/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo"),
    swSrc: resolveModule(resolveApp, "src/service-worker"),
    publicUrlOrPath,
};



module.exports.moduleFileExtensions = moduleFileExtensions;
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and your help would be appreciate.
Thanks !

Comment: What does `npm run start` do?

Comment: It starts the app as usual, but it becomes stuck at `Starting the development server...` and the page is loading indefinitely.

Comment: I mean what commands is it running, what does package.json look like?

Comment: `"start": "node scripts/start.js",`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a delayed answer, but just for future searches this is what I did.
In my case the requirement was to create pluggable components that can built/distributed/deployed separately.

My folder structure looks as follows

```
.
+-- app
|   +-- component1
|       +-- index.tsx
|       +-- all other component related code
|   +-- component2
|       +-- index.tsx
|       +-- all other component related code
|   +-- sharedComponent
+-- public
|   +-- index.html (template)
```

Steps I did:

```
npm run eject
```

Update npm command as follows

```
"build:component1": "node scripts/build.js --module=component1"
```

In you build script read this arg and set it in env

```
process.env.REACT_MODULE = nodeArgs.module;
```

Edit values in path.js

```
  appBuild: resolveApp(`${buildPath}/${buildModule}`),
  appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, `src/${buildModule}/index`),
```

This way you can build the components individually and each build will generate a main.js and index.html inside `/dist/<componentName>/`.